# Git remote pointing to itself on server

Tags: git

I'm a little bit confused how I got to this point, but the repo my server that I connect to from my machines when I do `git remote -v` is pointing to itself, so it sometimes gives funny warning notices.

```
git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@84.x.x.95/var/www/dating.co.uk (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@84.x.x.95/var/www/dating.co.uk (push)
```

Notices

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 120 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

Or

```
git push
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I realise I would never need to push, but it still irks me.

How can I just have it point to `localhost`? or something similar so I don't get these errors?

Comment: Call `git remote` with the appropriate URL or edit `.git/config` for the repo manually. Your remote can actually be a folder. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: You are not connecting to any server when you run [`git remote -v`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote). To check this disable the network and run `git remote -v`. The information displayed by most `git remote` subcommands (including the empty subcommand with or without `-v`) is retrieved from the local repository. Other Git commands (`fetch`, `pull`, `push` etc) use the information provided by `git remote` to know where to find a remote repository. `git push` fails because the access to the remote repository using public keys was incorrectly configured (or not configured at all).

Answer (score 0):

If you have double-checked that the origin remote of the server repo is really configured to be the repository itself, then you could probably just remove the remote to get rid of that warning.
 You still wouldn't be able to push in that case, as you would not have a defined remote to push to.

For understanding what the messages mean:

The error message you get when trying to push is because your server has a list of ssh-keys which are allowed to ssh to that machine, but the ssh key of your server is not in the list of allowed keys. Try doing `ssh localhost` from the server (in order to let the server try to ssh to itself) and you would get the same error. In order to allow the server machine to ssh to itself, you could simply allow access for the ssh key of the server. When you are logged into the server, do `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (This assumes that your server has an ssh key already). For more details see [this instruction for how to configure ssh authentication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server). After doing that, you should be able to run `git fetch`, `git pull` and `git push` commands (But pushing to and fetching from the repo itself doesn't really make a whole lot of sense).

The information message that you get when doing `git status` is not an error or a warning. A git repo maintains something called remote tracking branches. Remote tracking branches can be listed
 using `git branch -r`. A remote tracking branch is simply a record of the state of the remote branch **from when `git fetch` was last executed**. Since the remote of your repo is configured to be the repo itself, the local and remote branches cannot really diverge. However, since you have not ran `git fetch` recently, the remote tracking branches have not been updated. Simply run `git fetch`. This command will not make any changes to the objects in your git repo, but the remote tracking branches will be updated, and git status will say `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.`. For more detailed information about remote tracking branches, see [the Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches).